# Doctrine query in Symfony 1.4, not sure what I am doing wrong here

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have a query that reads like this:

```
$fields = Doctrine_Core::getTable('model_1')->findByColumnId($id);
```

took a var_dump on fields, and it retrieves data as it should ;

next up, I do this

```
foreach($fields as $field)
{
 $newerFields[$field->getColumnId()] =
 Doctrine_Core::getTable('model2')->findByColumn2Id($field->getColumnId());
}
```

I take a var_dump on each $newerFields[$field] and it does yield the result as it should. Next up I try and do this:

```
foreach($newerFields as $newerField)
{
 echo  $newerField->getColumn3();
}
```

But this spits out:
**Call to undefined method Doctrine_Collection::getColumn3() in actions.class.php on line 69**

I am not able to wrap my head around this and am flustered thinking on how to get it done. Can anyone spot the trouble for me?

Comment: if it is relational table you should use leftJoin()

Comment: it is a relational table but I don't get why I should be using a leftJoin in this case whatsoever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `findByColumn2Id` returns a Doctrine_Collection because `findBy` always returns a collection (if you don't define it in the table file) even if there is only one result. If you want to retrieve one result, use `findOneBy` instead.

Otherwise, you will have to loop on `newerFields` childs to retrieve data:

```
// array of Doctrine_Collection
foreach($newerFields as $newerFieldCollection)
{
  foreach($newerFieldCollection as $newerField)
  {
    echo $newerField->getColumn3();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out by myself and looping it is the solution since I am looking at a collection of records.